# Background linear-gradient right - top

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I am having a problem with setting up a gradient to single div.
See a picture.

Is it even possible to set it up top and right?
Thank you!

EDITED:
so far  `background: linear-gradient(to left, rgb(240, 240, 240),rgb(255, 255, 255) 3%) ;`

[image]

Comment: this more an inset box shadow... and yes it's possible top and right using multiple gradient but you need to share your code to show us what you tried so far to obtain what you want

Comment: Tried this and diffrent modifications:
 background: linear-gradient(to left, rgb(240, 240, 240),rgb(255, 255, 255) 3%) ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented above you can use multiple gradient and you should use transparent color instead of white so we can see both of them since they will overlap (you may use `background-color` for the white or simply add it to the background property at the end)

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
}

.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, rgb(40, 40, 40), transparent 3%), linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(40, 40, 40), transparent 3%);
  background-color: #fff;
}
.box-alt {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, rgb(40, 40, 40), transparent 3%),
  linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(40, 40, 40), transparent 3%),
  white;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>

<div class="box-alt">
</div>
```

You can go with more gradient and also different color for each side:

```css
.box {
 height:200px;
 width:200px;
 border:1px solid;
 background: linear-gradient(to left, rgb(200, 40, 0),transparent 3%),
 linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(200, 0, 200),transparent 3%),
 linear-gradient(to top, rgb(40, 0, 40),transparent 3%),
 linear-gradient(to right, rgb(40, 200, 0),transparent 3%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

You can also control size/position of each side:

```css
.box {
 height:200px;
 width:200px;
 border:1px solid;
 background: linear-gradient(to left, rgb(200, 40, 0),transparent 3%) 0 50%/100% 50% no-repeat,
 linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(200, 0, 200),transparent 3%) 40% 0/80% 100% no-repeat,
 linear-gradient(to top, rgb(40, 0, 40),transparent 3%) 80% 0/20% 100% no-repeat,
 linear-gradient(to right, rgb(40, 200, 0),transparent 3%) ;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Comment: Nice man! Appreciate it, it did make a trick, learn new thing make it work thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the ***box-shadow***

`box-shadow` syntax is defined as:

```
box-shadow: offset-x | offset-y | blur-radius | spread-radius | color | inset
```

In your case you have to use `inset` as you want the shadow inside the box.

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.shadow {
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: -4px 4px 10px 0 #eee inset;
}
```

```html
<div class="shadow"></div>
```